# fgets() getting skipped, how to clear user input?

Tags: c, user-input, fgets, scanf

I am using fgets() to get user input, and then I parse it into a double using sscanf(). Here is my example code:

```
int menuItem = 0;
char input[3];
printf("Enter valid menu item"); //values are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and -1
fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
sscanf(input, "%d", &menuItem);
```

The error occurs if the user enters 3 digits (invalid input, and I want to handle it accordingly), it skips my next fgets() by automatically placing the third digit as the next input. For example, if the user inters 123, it will now skip the next fgets and use the value 3 as the input. How can I clear this, or at most, only read 1 digit (but still being able to handle -1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just make your input array larger?  Like 50 bytes...  If the user enters that many, they are idiots and deserve strange behaviour =)

This is of course inelegant, but putting it in perspective, you are probably not writing industrial-strength code here.  You just want to fix a silly bug, and this is the simplest solution.

*[edit]*

In case you are confused as to why I suggested this.  Your input array is only large enough to hold 2 values, plus a null-terminator.  So obviously, you want it to be large enough that you can be sure the user entered a single choice and not two choices

Comment: Nice idea - I suppose you are right that it would be a rare occasion to enter that many digits anyways. I think I will most likely do what you suggest, but out of curiosity, how would I handle an error like that anyways? That is, say I make input[50], and they enter 80 characters. What would I have to do to clear those extra ones out of the buffer so they don't automatically get placed in the next fgets()?

Comment: Because `fgets` treats the newline character as valid, you can expect it in your string.  Therefore, you should always leave enough room for the characters you expect, plus a newline, plus a NULL-terminator.  Once you have your value, search for `\n`.  If you don't find it, call `fgets` again (and repeat).  You should really only do this if the maximum number of characters has been read.  This could cause problems in special cases (such as Ctrl-D) or other premature EOF (if reading files or piping).  It also needs special care because newline differs across operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

Your input buffer allows 1 digit, 1 newline, and 1 terminal null `'\0'`, which really isn't big enough.

Suppose the user types `100` followed by a newline.  The first call to `fgets()` will read 2 digits (`10`), then the second call will read the third digit and newline; then the next call will wait for the next input.

Simply increase your buffer size to something more sensible.  For a lot of programs that I write, I use a buffer size of 4096.  The POSIX standard sets _POSIX2_LINE_MAX to 2048.  If you're unhappy with that, simply go with a convenient number like 64 or 128; you won't go too far wrong.

Your technique with `fgets()` and `sscanf()` is definitely the better direction to go, but you should check that `sscanf()` parsed the correct number of values.   One of the advantages of `fgets()` plus `sscanf()` is that you can make better reports about what was erroneous in the line that the user entered; this is much less easy to do if you use `fscanf()` or `scanf()` directly.